# Android issue while using voice recognition

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am building an app which will be prompting the user to speak a few words and then comparing the words to a string and opening a new activity based on which string is spoken.
The code I am using is this:

```
    package com.example.voiceex;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static final int check=1111;
    static String res;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say Something");
                startActivityForResult(i, check);
            }
        });
        /*if("hello".equalsIgnoreCase(res))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hello is spoken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if("i am hungry".equalsIgnoreCase(res))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ill give you some food", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int request,int result,Intent data)
    {
        if(request==check&&result==RESULT_OK)
        {
            res=data.getStringExtra(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

}
```

The toast here is printed blank. And even the commented part is used, then also nothing happens. 
Where am i going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecognizerIntent returns array of matches you should determine your self which string you want to use usually it is first one form array

```
ArrayList matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
for(String match : matches){
    Log.i("Matched text", match);
}
```

Comment: i dont understand what the for(string match: matches) is doing. could you elaborate on that? thanks

Comment: It just iterates through arraylist and every match is printed to logcat you could simply use String match = matches.get(0);

Comment: and then i use the 'match' string and compare it with strings and based on condition, i carry out different functions? And will all this take place inside the 'for' itself?

Comment: thanks! i figured it out and it works !